# Data type in OaxacaBlinder decomposition in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels, decomposition

I can't find any information on this hence my question

What type of data should be used in the gender pay gap decomposition method using the **OaxacaBlinder** module in **Python**?

Are they supposed to be **binary** values for each variable?

For example:

I want to use variable 'marital status' i have four values there:
1- married, 2- widowed, 3- divorced, 4- unmarried.

Can it stay like this or change 'married status' and add four more variables so that each of them takes values 0-1?

I've tried both ways and I get different results for the explained and unexplained parts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.